# Exact sequence splits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

I am stuck in the following problem:

**Show that every group of order 4 is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Which of the exact sequences splits?**

Ok, i have to consider two cases for a group of order 4: $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, so i get two exact sequences:

$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}\overset{\psi }{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}_{4}\overset{\varphi }{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}_{2}\rightarrow 0$  and $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}\overset{\tilde{\psi} }{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}\overset{\tilde{\varphi} }{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}_{2}\rightarrow 0$

For both cases i checked the conditions of exact sequence and proved that these are exact sequences. Now i have a problem how to show if they split or not. 
We say that an exact sequence splits if for the first sequence there exists a group homomorphism $\pi :\mathbb{Z}_{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ with $\varphi \circ \pi =id_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}$ and for the second $\tilde{\varphi} \circ \tilde{\pi} =id_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}$, right? But how to show if these group homomorphisms exist or not?

Can anybody help me, please? I would appreciate any hints and comments.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Write down a set-theoretic splitting, with the constraint of preserving the identity element, and see if this defines a homomorphism of groups.

Comment: For $\pi$ to be a homomorphism you need the element of order $2$ to be sent to an element of order $1$ or $2$. It needs to be an inclusion if the composition is to be the identity, so the element of order $2$ needs to go to an element of order $2$. Think about what happens to elements of order $4$.

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ cannot be the direct sum of proper subgroups, because it has a single minimal subgroup.

Comment: Thank you all for for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2} \overset{\psi }{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_{4} \overset{\varphi }{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_{2}\rightarrow 0$$
and assume there is a splitting homomorphism $\pi:\Bbb Z_2 \to \Bbb Z_4$. What are the possible $\pi$? Well, $\pi(0) = 0$ is a given, and $\pi(1) \neq 0$ if we want $\varphi\circ\pi = id_{\Bbb Z_2}$. But we need to have $\pi(1) + \pi(1) = \pi(1+1) = \pi(0) = 0$ in $\Bbb Z_4$, which forces $\pi(1) = 2$.

Now, what does this say about the possibility of a splitting? Well, we want 
$$1 = id_{\Bbb Z_2}(1) = \varphi(\pi(1)) = \varphi(2) = \varphi(1+1) = \varphi(1) + \varphi(1) $$
(as elements of $\Bbb Z_2$). But this is impossible. This means that our assumption that there is such a $\pi$ must be false, and the sequence does not split.

On the other hand, for the sequence with the direct sum, it *does* split. Exactly *how* it splits depends on the details of $\bar\psi$ and $\bar\varphi$, but let's say that $\bar\psi(1) = (1, 0)$ and $\bar\phi(a, b) = b$. In that case, $\bar\pi(1) = (0, 1)$ works as a splitting homomorphism.

In general, when dealing with abelian groups, an exact sequence splits iff the middle term is the direct product of the right and left terms, $\psi$ is the corresponding inclusion and $\varphi$ is the corresponding projection. $\pi$ will be the corresponding inclusion ("opposite" of $\psi$).

Comment: Dear $Arthur$, than you very much for the great help!

Comment: Where is the proof for the assertion about abelian groups made in the last paragraph? Also, do you mean $\psi$ instead of $\phi$?

Comment: @Junglemath I believe I do mean $\psi$ rather than $\phi$. As for your other concern, clearly the direct product splits, so the crux is the other direction. One proof would be to use $\psi$ and $\varphi$, along with the two corresponding splitting homomorphisms to show that the middle element satisfies the universal property of direct products. (In fact, that sounds like a rather fun exercise.) So it isn't necessarily _the_ direct product, and $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are not necessarily the canonical inclusions and projections. But up to unique isomorphism, they are.

Comment: @Junglemath If you are very concerned about this, you could always just post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the exact sequence: $$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2} \overset{\psi }{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_{4} \overset{\varphi }{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_{2}\rightarrow 0$$
is split, then the group $\mathbb {Z}_{4}$ must be the semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Since the only automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is the identity so the action would be trivial. Hence $\mathbb {Z}_{4}$ becomes  the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.But this is impossible.