# Why isn't $1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$ a split extension?

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product, group-extensions

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ be the cyclic group of $n$ elements and $1$ the trivial group. I'm looking at the following extension:

$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$$

Because every action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on itself is trivial, the only split extension of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong V$ (the Klein group). But given that:

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{ (1 \bmod \mathbb{Z}_2), (x \bmod \mathbb{Z}_2)\} \text{ with } (x \bmod \mathbb{Z}_2)^2 = 1$$

A homomorphism $\psi: \mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ that sends $(x \bmod \mathbb{Z}_2) \mapsto y$ (consider $y$ the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_4$) isn't a splitting of the above sequence? Because going through $\psi$ and then back through the projection sure is the identity mapping.

I'm sure I'm missing something deeper, because I also can't answer the general case: given that $G$ is a extension of $N$ (normal) by $K$, and that $K \cong G/N$, doesn't the injection $K \to G$ which maps $(x \bmod N) \mapsto x$ always splits the sequence? I'm sure not, but why?

Comment: It's already answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478880/266711

Comment: I hope you don't mind my changing the `\mod`s for `\bmod`s, the spacing was a little extreme (the 'b' is for *binary*).

Comment: @pjs36 good to know of that command, the extra space always bothered me and made my notes look strange!